# Is it possible to use Hive 0.12 with Impala on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr, impala

I am hoping to run Hive 0.12 since the Parquet compatibility with Impala is broken in Hive 0.13. But the only options when setting up the cluster seem to be Hadoop 1, which doesn't support Impala, and Hadoop 2 which only allows Hive 0.13 to be selected.

Is it worth trying to manually install Hive 0.12 on a Hadoop 2 cluster? Or is this a recipe for pain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From release notes it says, Hive 0.12 supports Hadoop 1.x.y and Hadop2.x.y. So you should be good.

```
15 October, 2013: release 0.12.0 available
This release works with Hadoop 0.20.x, 0.23.x.y, 1.x.y, 2.x.y
```